# Get a structured value from string field on BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a string field on BigQuery which looks like this:

```
[{"value": "yes", "source": "CURATED", "curated": true}, {"value": "yes", "source": "listing_service", "curated": false}]
```

How can I query this field if I only like to know the value parameter which in this case is `yes`?

Answer (score 2):

Consider below approach

```
select 
  json_value(entry, '$.value') as value,
  json_value(entry, '$.source') as source,
  json_value(entry, '$.curated') as curated
from your_table, unnest(json_extract_array(field_name)) entry
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile I found the solution for this with the function `JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR`
The exact example could be queried like this.

```js
JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(field_name,"$[0].value")
```

Answer (score 1):

To complement your answer, `JSON_Extract_SCALAR` is a good way to extract data but its consider legacy as show on [JSON functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions) documentation page. I would suggest to use `JSON_VALUE` instead.

```
select JSON_VALUE('[{"name":"juliana","country":"peru"}]',"$[0].name") as name
```

output

```
name 
-------
juliana
```